# Display UIActivityIndicatorView while loading the application

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview, default.png

I checked other questions and found none with my doubt.

Is there a way to display an UIActivityIndicatorView "on top" of Default.png while my iPhone application is being loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Camilo @ lx-apps.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste a (static) indicator view image on top of Default.png. Of course it won't animate.

Other than that you can't do anything because the app isn't loaded yet, so none of your UI code will run.

Comment: Oh damn! Well, thanks for the help anyway. Guess I'll have to change the data loading to somewhere else in the application, and not when it is loading.

Comment: @camilo: You can update the UI to anything on `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, then do the data loading.

Comment: Iep, that was what I was thinking. It will not be a big change in the code, fortunately. Thanks for the tip.